# Why do Top-Aligned Minipages Create a Vertical Margin?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, margins

Using the following bit of code, I experience unwanted behaviour.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe, margin=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{14mm}
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[height=17mm]{Placeholder.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{100mm}
\flushright
\vspace{0pt}
Lorem Ipsum\\
dolor sit amet\\
consetetur sadipscing elitr
\end{minipage}
\vspace*{50mm}

\today

\end{document}
```

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzu9.png

Where does the vertical space between frame and content of the minipages come from and how can I eliminate it?

I tried these things:

- No `\vspace{0pt}`. The logo placeholder moves to the frame (where I
  want it), but the text moves down more.
- `\vspace{0pt}` only in first minipage. Text moves up to the frame (where I want it), but logo placeholder has the unwanted margin.
- Minipages with given height of 25 mm via `\begin{minipage}[t][25mm]{100mm}`. No effect.

I've had these issues with minipages for a long time. Maybe I misunderstood something? I'm also grateful for hints on how to achieve what I want with other methods than minipages.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for your first solution with no `\vspace{0pt}`. To get the correct image alignment, you can use the `valign` option from the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe, margin=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}%
\includegraphics[height=17mm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{100mm}
\flushright
Lorem Ipsum\\
dolor sit amet\\
consetetur sadipscing elitr
\end{minipage}%

\vspace*{50mm}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image]